# How to make a texture always face the camera ..?

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, texture-mapping, uv-mapping

**Update 5**

Created another fiddle to show what is expected would look like. An invisible skydome and a cubecamera are added and environment map is used; in my case, none of these technique should be used for the reasons already mentioned.

```js
var MatcapTransformer = function(uvs, face) {
  for (var i = uvs.length; i-- > 0;) {
    uvs[i].x = face.vertexNormals[i].x * 0.5 + 0.5;
    uvs[i].y = face.vertexNormals[i].y * 0.5 + 0.5;
  }
};

var TransformUv = function(geometry, xformer) {
  // The first argument is also used as an array in the recursive calls 
  // as there's no method overloading in javascript; and so is the callback. 
  var a = arguments[0],
    callback = arguments[1];

  var faceIterator = function(uvFaces, index) {
    xformer(uvFaces[index], geometry.faces[index]);
  };

  var layerIterator = function(uvLayers, index) {
    TransformUv(uvLayers[index], faceIterator);
  };

  for (var i = a.length; i-- > 0;) {
    callback(a, i);
  }

  if (!(i < 0)) {
    TransformUv(geometry.faceVertexUvs, layerIterator);
  }
};

var SetResizeHandler = function(renderer, camera) {
  var callback = function() {
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  };

  // bind the resize event
  window.addEventListener('resize', callback, false);

  // return .stop() the function to stop watching window resize
  return {
    stop: function() {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', callback);
    }
  };
};

(function() {
  var fov = 45;
  var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

  var texture = loader.load('https://i.postimg.cc/mTsN30vx/canyon-s.jpg');
  texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  texture.center.set(1 / 2, 1 / 2);

  var cubeCam = new THREE.CubeCamera(.1, 200, 4096);
  cubeCam.renderTarget.texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  cubeCam.renderTarget.texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  cubeCam.renderTarget.texture.center.set(1 / 2, 1 / 2);

  var geoSky = new THREE.SphereGeometry(2, 16, 16);
  var matSky = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    'map': texture,
    'side': THREE.BackSide
  });
  var meshSky = new THREE.Mesh(geoSky, matSky);
  meshSky.visible = false;

  var geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(1, 1);
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    'envMap': cubeCam.renderTarget.texture
  });
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  var geoWireframe = new THREE.WireframeGeometry(geometry);
  var matWireframe = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    'color': 'red',
    'linewidth': 2
  });
  mesh.add(new THREE.LineSegments(geoWireframe, matWireframe));

  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect);
  camera.position.setZ(20);

  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.add(mesh);
  scene.add(meshSky);

  {
    var mirror = new THREE.CubeCamera(.1, 2000, 4096);
    var geoPlane = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(16, 16);
    var matPlane = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      'envMap': mirror.renderTarget.texture
    });

    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geoPlane, matPlane);
    plane.add(mirror);
    plane.position.setZ(-4);
    plane.lookAt(mesh.position);
    scene.add(plane);
  }

  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

  var container = document.getElementById('container1');
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  SetResizeHandler(renderer, camera);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, container);

  var fixTextureWhenRotateAroundAllAxis = function() {
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
    mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
    mesh.rotation.z += 0.01;

    cubeCam.update(renderer, scene);
  };

  renderer.setAnimationLoop(function() {
    // controls.update();

    plane.visible = false;

    {
      meshSky.visible = true;
      mesh.visible = false;

      fixTextureWhenRotateAroundAllAxis();

      mesh.visible = true;

      meshSky.visible = false;
    }

    mirror.update(renderer, scene);
    plane.visible = true;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  });
})();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>

<div id='container1'></div>
```

---

**Update 4**

Important: Please note there is a reflective plane in back of the target mesh which is for observing if the texture binds to the mesh surface correctly, it has nothing to do with what I'm trying to solve.

---

**Update 3**

Created a new fiddle to show what is NOT the expected behaviour

- Code

```js
var MatcapTransformer=function(uvs, face) {
 for(var i=uvs.length; i-->0;) {
  uvs[i].x=face.vertexNormals[i].x*0.5+0.5;
  uvs[i].y=face.vertexNormals[i].y*0.5+0.5;
 }
};

var TransformUv=function(geometry, xformer) {
 // The first argument is also used as an array in the recursive calls 
 // as there's no method overloading in javascript; and so is the callback. 
 var a=arguments[0], callback=arguments[1];

 var faceIterator=function(uvFaces, index) {
  xformer(uvFaces[index], geometry.faces[index]);
 };

 var layerIterator=function(uvLayers, index) {
  TransformUv(uvLayers[index], faceIterator);
 };

 for(var i=a.length; i-->0;) {
  callback(a, i);
 }

 if(!(i<0)) {
  TransformUv(geometry.faceVertexUvs, layerIterator);
 }
};

var SetResizeHandler=function(renderer, camera) {
 var callback=function() {
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  camera.aspect=window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
 };

 // bind the resize event
 window.addEventListener('resize', callback, false);

 // return .stop() the function to stop watching window resize
 return {
  stop: function() {
   window.removeEventListener('resize', callback);
  }
 };
};

 var getVertexShader=function() {
  return `
void main() {
 gl_Position=projectionMatrix*modelViewMatrix*vec4(position, 1.0);
}
`;
 };

 var getFragmentShader=function(size) {
  return `
uniform sampler2D texture1;
const vec2 size=vec2(`+size.x+`, `+size.y+`);

void main() {
 gl_FragColor=texture2D(texture1, gl_FragCoord.xy/size.xy);
}
`;
 };


(function() {
 var fov=45;
 var aspect=window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight;
 var loader=new THREE.TextureLoader();

 var texture=loader.load('https://i.postimg.cc/mTsN30vx/canyon-s.jpg');
 texture.wrapS=THREE.RepeatWrapping;
 texture.wrapT=THREE.RepeatWrapping;
 texture.center.set(1/2, 1/2);

 var geometry=new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 16, 16);
 // var geometry=new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2);

 // var material=new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 'map': texture });
 var material=new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  'uniforms': { 'texture1': { 'type': 't', 'value': texture } }
  , 'vertexShader': getVertexShader()
  , 'fragmentShader': getFragmentShader({ 'x': 512, 'y': 256 })
 });

 var mesh=new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
 var geoWireframe=new THREE.WireframeGeometry(geometry);
 var matWireframe=new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ 'color': 'red', 'linewidth': 2 });
 mesh.add(new THREE.LineSegments(geoWireframe, matWireframe));

 var camera=new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect);
 camera.position.setZ(20);

 var scene=new THREE.Scene();
 scene.add(mesh);
  
 {
  var mirror=new THREE.CubeCamera(.1, 2000, 4096);
  var geoPlane=new THREE.PlaneGeometry(16, 16);
  var matPlane=new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
   'envMap': mirror.renderTarget.texture
  });

  var plane=new THREE.Mesh(geoPlane, matPlane);
  plane.add(mirror);
  plane.position.setZ(-4);
  plane.lookAt(mesh.position);
  scene.add(plane);
 }

 var renderer=new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

 var container=document.getElementById('container1');
 container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

 SetResizeHandler(renderer, camera);
 renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

 var fixTextureWhenRotateAroundYAxis=function() {
  mesh.rotation.y+=0.01;
  texture.offset.set(mesh.rotation.y/(2*Math.PI), 0);
 };

 var fixTextureWhenRotateAroundZAxis=function() {
  mesh.rotation.z+=0.01;
  texture.rotation=-mesh.rotation.z
  TransformUv(geometry, MatcapTransformer);
 };

 var fixTextureWhenRotateAroundAllAxis=function() {
  mesh.rotation.y+=0.01;
  mesh.rotation.x+=0.01;
  mesh.rotation.z+=0.01;
 };
  
 var controls=new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, container);

 renderer.setAnimationLoop(function() {
   fixTextureWhenRotateAroundAllAxis();

   controls.update();
   plane.visible=false;
   mirror.update(renderer, scene);
   plane.visible=true;   

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
 });
})();
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #000;
 margin: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>

<div id='container1'></div>
```

Maybe I should rephrase my question, but I lack the knowledge to describe accurately about what I'm trying to solve, please help .. (Panoramic-Transform-With-Texture-Looking-At-Direction-Locked-Onto-The-Camera maybe .. ?)

---

**Update 2**

(Has deprecated as code snippet is applied. )

---

**Update**

OK .. I've added 3 methods:

- `TransformUv` accepts a geometry, and a transformer method which handles uv-transform. The callback accepts an uvs array for each face and the corresponding `Face3` of `geometry.faces[]` as its parameters.
- `MatcapTransformer` is the uv-transform handler callback to do the matcap transform.

  and
- `fixTextureWhenRotateAroundZAxis` works like what it named.

So far none of the `fixTexture..` methods can work alltogether, also, `fixTextureWhenRotateAroundXAxis` is not figured out. The problem remains unsolved, I wish what's just added could help you to help me out.

---

I'm trying to make the texture of a mesh always face an active perspective camera, no matter what are the relative positions.

For constructing a real case of my scene and the interaction would be quite complex, I built a minimal example to demonstrate my intention.

- Code

  ```js
  var MatcapTransformer=function(uvs, face) {
   for(var i=uvs.length; i-->0;) {
    uvs[i].x=face.vertexNormals[i].x*0.5+0.5;
    uvs[i].y=face.vertexNormals[i].y*0.5+0.5;
   }
  };

  var TransformUv=function(geometry, xformer) {
   // The first argument is also used as an array in the recursive calls 
   // as there's no method overloading in javascript; and so is the callback. 
   var a=arguments[0], callback=arguments[1];

   var faceIterator=function(uvFaces, index) {
    xformer(uvFaces[index], geometry.faces[index]);
   };

   var layerIterator=function(uvLayers, index) {
    TransformUv(uvLayers[index], faceIterator);
   };

   for(var i=a.length; i-->0;) {
    callback(a, i);
   }

   if(!(i<0)) {
    TransformUv(geometry.faceVertexUvs, layerIterator);
   }
  };

  var SetResizeHandler=function(renderer, camera) {
   var callback=function() {
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect=window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
   };

   // bind the resize event
   window.addEventListener('resize', callback, false);

   // return .stop() the function to stop watching window resize
   return {
    stop: function() {
     window.removeEventListener('resize', callback);
    }
   };
  };

  (function() {
   var fov=45;
   var aspect=window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight;
   var loader=new THREE.TextureLoader();

   var texture=loader.load('https://i.postimg.cc/mTsN30vx/canyon-s.jpg');
   texture.wrapS=THREE.RepeatWrapping;
   texture.wrapT=THREE.RepeatWrapping;
   texture.center.set(1/2, 1/2);

   var geometry=new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 16, 16);
   var material=new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 'map': texture });
   var mesh=new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

   var geoWireframe=new THREE.WireframeGeometry(geometry);
   var matWireframe=new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ 'color': 'red', 'linewidth': 2 });
   mesh.add(new THREE.LineSegments(geoWireframe, matWireframe));

   var camera=new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect);
   camera.position.setZ(20);

   var scene=new THREE.Scene();
   scene.add(mesh);
    
   {
    var mirror=new THREE.CubeCamera(.1, 2000, 4096);
    var geoPlane=new THREE.PlaneGeometry(16, 16);
    var matPlane=new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
     'envMap': mirror.renderTarget.texture
    });

    var plane=new THREE.Mesh(geoPlane, matPlane);
    plane.add(mirror);
    plane.position.setZ(-4);
    plane.lookAt(mesh.position);
    scene.add(plane);
   }

   var renderer=new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

   var container=document.getElementById('container1');
   container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

   SetResizeHandler(renderer, camera);
   renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

   var fixTextureWhenRotateAroundYAxis=function() {
    mesh.rotation.y+=0.01;
    texture.offset.set(mesh.rotation.y/(2*Math.PI), 0);
   };

   var fixTextureWhenRotateAroundZAxis=function() {
    mesh.rotation.z+=0.01;
    texture.rotation=-mesh.rotation.z
    TransformUv(geometry, MatcapTransformer);
   };

   // This is wrong
   var fixTextureWhenRotateAroundAllAxis=function() {
    mesh.rotation.y+=0.01;
    mesh.rotation.x+=0.01;
    mesh.rotation.z+=0.01;

    // Dun know how to do it correctly .. 
    texture.offset.set(mesh.rotation.y/(2*Math.PI), 0);
   };
    
   var controls=new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, container);

   renderer.setAnimationLoop(function() {
    fixTextureWhenRotateAroundYAxis();

    // Uncomment the following line and comment out `fixTextureWhenRotateAroundYAxis` to see the demo
    // fixTextureWhenRotateAroundZAxis();

    // fixTextureWhenRotateAroundAllAxis();
      
    // controls.update();
    plane.visible=false;
    mirror.update(renderer, scene);
    plane.visible=true; 
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
   });
  })();
  ```

  ```css
  body {
   background-color: #000;
   margin: 0px;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>

  <div id='container1'></div>
  ```

Please note that although the mesh itself rotates in this demonstration, my real intention is making the camera move like orbiting around the mesh.

I've added the wireframe to make the movement more clear. As you can see
 I use `fixTextureWhenRotateAroundYAxis` to do it correctly, but it's only for the y-axis. The `mesh.rotation.y` in my real code is calculated something like

```
var ve=camera.position.clone();
ve.sub(mesh.position);
var rotY=Math.atan2(ve.x, ve.z);
var offsetX=rotY/(2*Math.PI);
```

However, I lack the knowledge of how to do `fixTextureWhenRotateAroundAllAxis` correctly. There are some restrictions of solving this:

- CubeCamera/CubeMap cannot be used as the client machines might have performance issues
- Do not simply make the mesh `lookAt` the camera as they are eventually of any kind of geometry, not only the spheres; tricks like `lookAt` and restore `.quaternion` in a frame would be ok.

Please don't get me wrong that I'm asking an XY problem as I don't have the right to expose proprietary code or I wouldn't have to pay the effort to build a minimal example :)

Comment: Do you know GLSL shader language? The only way to achieve this effect is to write a custom shader that overrides the default behavior of UV coordinates.

Comment: @Marquizzo I'm no expert at GLSL, however, I've dug some source code of three.js like WebGLRenderTargetCube; I can find the GLSL wrapped with ShaderMaterial. Like I've told, 'm lacking knowledges around this and it would be too much to drink at the moment. I believe three.js wrapped GLSL good enough and also lightweight enough that I thought we can achive things like this using the library without dealing with GLSL ourselves.

Comment: Sorry, but the only way I can think of doing this is through GLSL, since the textures are always drawn in the shader, and you're trying to change the default way the texture position is calculated. You might have better luck asking this type of "how to" questions at https://discourse.threejs.org/

Comment: I can confirm, that's solvable in GPU pipeline by a pixel shader

Answer (score 7):

Facing the camera will look like:

[image]

Or, even better, as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164642/shader-texture-always-facing-the-camera), where the opposite fix is asked:

[image]

To achieve that, you have to setup a simple fragment shader (as the OP 
accidentally did):

**Vertex shader**

```
void main() {
  gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

**Fragment shader**

```
uniform vec2 size;
uniform sampler2D texture;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, gl_FragCoord.xy / size.xy);
}
```

**A working mock of the shader with Three.js**

```js
function main() {
  // Uniform texture setting
  const uniforms = {
    texture1: { type: "t", value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/wall.jpg" ) }
  };
  // Material by shader
   const myMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: uniforms,
        vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
        fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentShader').textContent
      });
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 2;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const boxWidth = 1;
  const boxHeight = 1;
  const boxDepth = 1;
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);

  const cubes = [];  // just an array we can use to rotate the cubes
  
  const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, myMaterial);
  scene.add(cube);
  cubes.push(cube);  // add to our list of cubes to rotate

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;
    
    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    cubes.forEach((cube, ndx) => {
      const speed = .2 + ndx * .1;
      const rot = time * speed;
      
      
      cube.rotation.x = rot;
      cube.rotation.y = rot;      
    });
   

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#c {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/109/three.min.js"></script>
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
  void main() {
    gl_Position =   projectionMatrix * 
                    modelViewMatrix * 
                    vec4(position,1.0);
  }
</script>

<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
  uniform sampler2D texture1;
  const vec2  size = vec2(1024, 512);
  
  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture1,gl_FragCoord.xy/size.xy); 
  }
</script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

**A viable alternative: Cube Mapping**

Here I've modified a jsfiddle about *cube mapping*, maybe is what are you looking for:

https://jsfiddle.net/v8efxdo7/

The cube project its face texture on the underlying object and it's looking at the camera.

**Note:** lights changes with rotation because light and inner object are in fixed position, while *camera* and projection cube rotates both around the center of the scene.

If you carefully look to the example, this technique is not perfect, but what are you looking for (applied to a box) is tricky, because the UV unwrap of the texture of a cube is cross-shaped, rotating the UV itself will not be effective and using projection techniques has its drawbacks too, because the projector object shape and projection subject shape matters.

Just for better understanding: in the real world, where do you see this effect in 3d space on boxes ? The only example that comes in my mind is a 2D projection on a 3D surface (like projection mapping in visual design).

Comment: More of the former one. Would you please use three.js to do it? I'm not familiar with GLSL. And I'm curious what will happen if the cube in the first animation you show rotates around every axis at the same time? After you provide the your implementation using three.js, I'll try and see if my question get solved. Looks promising :)

Comment: Hi mate, I've added a codepen with a simple demo reproducing the shader you need.

Comment: As I tested your implementation, it looks like that the mesh is a viewport to display the image and lost the morphing affected by the geometry. Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/evow05xu/). This is not what I want. In my example, the texture is rendered on the surface of the mesh and keeps the direction where the texture is facing to. By the way, I can't see where the `position` of `vec4(position,1.0)` comes from .. would you mind to add a little bit of explanation about it .. ?

Comment: It does not lose the morphing, if the texture _always_ face the camera, the effect will be _always_ of a plain texture, if the env has no lights or the material does not cast shadows. Attributes and uniforms like _position_ are  provided by _Geometry_ and _BufferGeometry_ so you do not have to retrieve them in other places. Three.js docs have a nice section about it: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram

Comment: I created a new [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qak46m5e/) and put a reflective plane as a mirror(`CubeCamera` is used of course) in back of the mesh to observe it. As you can see it doesn't seem that when the image binds as the surface texture will look like that in the back view ..

Comment: Hi mate, your cubecamera settings seems to be wrong, try (Eg) `var mirror=new THREE.CubeCamera(1, 10000, 128);`

Comment: Please take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/7k9so2fr/ of the revised one. I'd say that this behaviour of texture binding isn't what I'm trying to achieve :( ..

Comment: What do you expect to see as reflection ?

Comment: The reflection is just for observing if the texture bound as expected -- not to repeat more than once when the distance to the camera changes, morphs like it maps to the surface of mesh, be consistent in any point of view as it's really a texture of that surface like my snippet shows ..The back view or any other point of view are not the matter to solve, but the consistency is;  that's why I thought I should rephrace my question ..

Comment: The effect are you looking for is very tricky, take a look at the last jsfiddle I've linked, may be this is a solution that can work for you.

Comment: I know the UV unwrapping makes effects, and for some geometries, might need to be re-calculated like it was equirectangular-projection. In real world I think environment reflection may be a pretty general case which is similar, though I should not use those techniques. I award the bounty anyway as I do not have enough time to check if your update solved this, and will mark it as accepeted if it does.